# RadioGroup button images cut off

Tags: android, android-layout, android-resolution

I have a RadioGroup at the bottom with four buttons acting as a navigation for my application (I know this is non-standard for an Android app, but it's what the client wanted).  This is the way it should look:

[image: Radio Buttons - Correct]

This looks fine on my Nexus 7, and it looks fine across the Emulators and Previews in my IDE.  However, when I load it onto a Galaxy S Note 2, this is how it looks:

[image: Radio Buttons - Incorrect]

The images are cutoff, as it seems they are "shifted" to the right for this particular device.  I have a feeling that on smaller devices, it will be even more skewed and cutoff.  When I manually do a negative left margin of around 35dp, it actually looks perfect and they align great (but of course that solution doesn't work for other devices).

What's strange is that it doesn't seem that I'm doing anything special in my code, and it's seemingly pretty straight-forward.  FYI, even when I change it to just three buttons, it **still** shifts the buttons to the right, not really centering them (although they aren't cutoff when there are only 3).  I just can't figure out why it's doing this, no matter how many things I try out with tweaking gravity, weight, and even swapping out images.  I'm currently only using /xhdpi images for these, and the sizes of each are around 130x130 each.

For reference, here is the underlying code for the RadioGroup in my layout file (it's in a RelativeLayout):

```
    <RadioGroup
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/tab_radio_group"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:background="@drawable/navigation_base"
            android:paddingTop="15dp">
        <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/button_scan"
                style="@style/navbar_button"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/scan"/>
        <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/button_view_order"
                style="@style/navbar_button"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/view_order"/>
        <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/button_complete_order"
                style="@style/navbar_button"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/complete_order"/>
        <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/button_settings"
                style="@style/navbar_button"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/settings"/>
    </RadioGroup>
```

And here is the style element for navbar_button:

```
    <style name="navbar_button">
        <item name="android:layout_width">0dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:button">@null</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">center_horizontal</item>
        <item name="android:layout_weight">1</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">12dp</item>
    </style>
```

I may be missing something obvious here, but any thoughts on this?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm pretty sure you thought of it already, but, did you try smaller images? Also, it seems that the Settings icon does not get cut off. Is that right?

Comment: I did indeed try re-sizing them down to around 100x100, and it still cuts off the images, even though it adds even more padding between them.  And good point about the Settings button, it doesn't seem like that one is getting cutoff, although it runs off the screen.   It seems as if the buttons are getting cutoff at exactly 25%, 50%, and 75% of the screen's width.  Not sure if that makes a difference or not, but I felt it was worth noting.

Comment: you should have 3 sets of images, 36x36 ldpi, 48x48 mdpi and 96x96 hdpi dpi

Comment: Yep, I tried that as well.  My images in the /xhdpi and /hdpi folders are the original sizes (130x130), and I added 65x65 ones into the /mdpi folder, as well as 50x50 ones in the /ldpi folder.  Still the exact same issue, and it looks the same. :(

Comment: In addition, I tried adding smaller images to the /hdpi folder and below, and it does indeed seem to use the smaller ones.  But it still cuts them off and right-aligns them!  Very strange..

Comment: I ran into the exact same issue. Pretty anoying...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix this, I ended up having to abandon the RadioGroup and RadioButtons, and I went with a simple Linear Layout with Buttons.  It still made for relatively simple code, and it just involved changing up the Java code a bit to work with normal Buttons rather than RadioButtons.  Here is the changed layout, if interested:

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:id="@+id/tab_radio_group"
              android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
              android:orientation="horizontal"
              android:background="@drawable/navigation_base"
              android:paddingTop="15dp">

    <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_scan"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/scan"/>
    <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_view_order"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/view_order"/>
    <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_complete_order"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/complete_order"/>
    <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_settings"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/settings"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's the only problem, but I've found that in function `setButtonDrawable()` there is a call to `setMinHeight(mButtonDrawable.getIntrinsicHeight());` but there's no call to `setMinWidth()`, so I've extended `RadioButton` class and have overwritten the function like this:

```java
@Override
public void setButtonDrawable(Drawable d) {
    super.setButtonDrawable(d);
    if (d != null) {
        setMinWidth(d.getIntrinsicWidth());
        refreshDrawableState();
    }
}
```